# ArgumentError in Admin::ProductsController#create wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bug that I can't resolve. After I install `mini_magick`, I want to upload a picture to my product. But it will give me the following error:

> ArgumentError in Admin::ProductsController#create wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)

It's the first time I've asked a question here. If you want to know more informatian, please let me know. Thank you very much for helping me.

[image: rails log].

[image: controller].

Comment: Pls reframe your question again.is it referring to NilClass error on the view page or the wrong number of arguments mentioned in the question.Kindly be specific. :)

Comment: It is the wrong number of arguments.:)

Comment: You need to ask a specific question, along with how you tried to understand the error message you are getting. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: In future please post the related code inside the question rather than linking to images offsite.

Comment: @jacefarm,Ok,I will read it

Comment: @Deepak Thank you for your edit~~ :)

Comment: @KScandrett I will pay attention next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error messages, the problem is that you're trying to call the `image` method on `@product` which is `nil`. It should actually be `product` as it is the local variable with which you're iterating the records.

```
<%= link_to product_path(product) do %>
  <% if product.image.present? %>
    <%= image_tag product.image.medium.url, class: 'thumbnail' %>
  ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm sorry,I can't understand it totally.I m a new comer.What should I do as the problem?can you tell me more?

Comment: @代小瘦  You're using `@product` in your index template(`index.html.erb`). Replace that with `product` as `@product` is not actually defined in the controller and is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

As the Rails log error message states, the problem lies on Line 27 of your `admin/products/index.html.erb` template.

On that line you are referencing an instance variable `@product` which is not defined for that action (`Admin::ProductsController#index`).

Since you are in an index template, you are likely looping over the `@products` collection, in which case you probably meant to call the **local** variable `product`, not the **instance variable** `@product`.

Try changing it to

```
<%= if product.image.present? %>
  <%= image_tag(product.image.medium.url, class: "thumbnail" %>
```